# Guide about NagiosGrapher on Debian?

Tags: debian, nagios

I have Nagios 3 on Debian Lenny up and running, but trying to install the *NagiosGrapher* plugin has proven to be frustrating to say the least - the plugin doesn't work by itself, there seems to be close to no documentation about how to make it work under Debian, the service refuses even to start (it throws some Perl-related errors instead), the *official* installation guide included in the package is a 1-line file pointing to a non-existent directory and my chair is uncomfortable (that last thing may be unrelated, though).

I tried searching online, without luck. While I did found a couple guides, all of them start with "download the source code from...", but I *really* wish I could install it the "Debian" way if possible - don't forget that, since those guides are for non-Debian systems, the files are located in different places, making every step harder.

Anyone knows where can I find an installation guide/howto? Or at least a first-hand experience of painless installation under Debian with source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `dpkg-reconfigure nagiosgrapher` and take a look at `/usr/share/doc/nagiosgrapher`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a few changes.

In `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg`
change

```
process_performance_data=0
```

to

```
process_performance_data=1
```

then add

```
service_perfdata_command=ngraph-process-service-perfdata-pipe
```

In `/etc/nagiosgrapher/ngraph.ncfg`
I changed `fe_use_browser_all` to true because I'm not logged in as `nagiosadmin`.